# Initializing a generic Swift enum from another generic enum?

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I'm trying to write an initializer for my generic enum which takes Alamofire's generic Result enum and converts it to my own Result type. What I've come up with is the following:

```
public enum Result<Value, Error: ErrorType> {
    case Success(Value)
    case Failure(Error)

    public init(result: Alamofire.Result) {
        switch(result) {
        case Alamofire.Result.Success(let val):
            self = MyFramework.Result.Success(val)
        case Alamofire.Result.Failure(let err):
            self = MyFramework.Result.Failure(err)
        }
    }
}
```

However I am running into the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'Success' with an argument list of type '(Value)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the way the compiler infers the generic arguments of `Alamofire.Result`.

You can fix it by changing

```
init(result: Alamofire.Result) {
```

to

```
init(result: Alamofire.Result<Value, Error>) {
```

That way, the generic arguments are specified explicitly (to be the same as the arguments of your Result type).

I'd also recommend you [file a bug](https://bugs.swift.org), because the error message this gave was pretty unhelpful.

Comment: Explicitly specifying the generic arguments gets rid of the weird compiler error, but resolving that issue uncovers an even weirder segfault. After playing around with it some more, it seems that the references to `MyFramework` are what's causing it. Any thoughts as to why that might be the case? I've summarized my findings in my answer.

Comment: I didn't notice that when I was testing this, but then your code is in a more complex environment than my simple test file. Again, I think you should file a bug at bugs.swift.org so that someone can take a look at it (if it's not already a known issue).

Comment: Will do; I'm going to try and isolate the issue further before submitting a bug report. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As jtbandes suggested, explicitly specifying the generic argument types gets rid of the cryptic compiler error. However, once this is resolved I run into an even more cryptic segfault.

After some playing around, removing the reference to `MyFramework` seems to resolve the segfault for whatever reason. The following code compiles fine:

```
public enum Result<Value, Error: ErrorType> {
    case Success(Value)
    case Failure(Error)

    public init(result: Alamofire.Result<Value, Error>) {
        switch(result) {
        case Alamofire.Result.Success(let val):
            self = .Success(val)
        case Alamofire.Result.Failure(let err):
            self = .Failure(err)
        }
    }
}
```